# redirect after axios method submit on successful result

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i have a form which i am using axios to submit a form in my laravel app like below :

```
<script>
export default {
  props: [ 'route' ],

  data: function () {
    return {
      mobile: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    submitMobile(){
      axios.post('/customer/send-sms', {
        mobile: this.mobile
      })
          .then(response => {
           console.log(response.data)

          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
          });
    }
  },
}

</script>
```

now i know it may not possible but after submiting the form if the user mobile is valid and all other conditions that i check i want to redirect user to the page that enters the the verify code

Comment: assuming that you have set up your vuejs routes. you can do `.then( () => { this.$router.push("/verify-code") })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Vue router, then in your axios then block, you could do something like:

```js
.then(() => this.$router.push('/verify-path'))
```

If not, there are [lots of different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage) to achieve the same with vanilla javascript.